# How can I fix this code for printing a centralized triangle?

Tags: python

I am trying to print a trianlge in a way like shown below(might be misshown here but it is the upper part of a diamond):

```
   1
  1 1
 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

I did some paper work made an algorithm but it went wrong and it is printing a rhombus now!

This is the code:

```
currentRow = 1
maxRows = int(input("Enter the maximum number of rows: "))
while currentRow <= maxRows:
    spaces = maxRows - currentRow
    while spaces > 0:
        print(" ", end='')
        spaces -= 1
    stars = maxRows - spaces
    while stars > 0:
        print("*", end='')
        stars -= 1
    print()
    currentRow += 1
```

Output:

```
D:\Python\diamond\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/Python/diamond/main.py
Enter the maximum number of rows: 4
   ****
  ****
 ****
****
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close to the solution that I'm sorry to give it to you:

```
Enter the maximum number of rows: 4
   * 
  * * 
 * * * 
* * * * 

currentRow = 1
maxRows = int(input("Enter the maximum number of rows: "))
while currentRow <= maxRows:
    spaces = maxRows - currentRow
    while spaces > 0:
        print(" ", end='')
        spaces -= 1
    stars = currentRow
    while stars > 0:
        print("*", end=' ')
        stars -= 1
    print()
    currentRow += 1
```

I changed two lines:

```
stars = currentRow
```

And:

```
print("*", end=' ')
```

(I added a space )

Comment: Really I first thought to set stars to this value on paper but when coding I forgot it lol

Comment: Also just gimme a bit of hint(without code) how should I modify it to create a full diamond shape

Comment: High level hint:  Same code  can print a triangle upside down - just swap the number of spaces and stars you print.  Details:   Copy the while loop and reinitialize currentRow to 1, but change the calculations for the initial values of spaces and stars (they are basically swapped).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
max_rows = int(input("Enter the maximum number of rows: "))

for row in range(1, max_rows+1):
    print(' '*(max_rows-row) + '* '*row)
```

Output:

```
Enter the maximum number of rows: 4
   * 
  * * 
 * * * 
* * * *
```

Comment: I am a beginner but this code is so small never even expected that this code could be so much simplified but thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
currentRow = 1
maxRows = int(input("Enter the maximum number of rows: "))
while currentRow <= maxRows:
    spaces = maxRows - currentRow
    while spaces > 0:
        print(" ", end='')
        spaces -= 1
    stars = currentRow
    while stars > 0:
        print("* ", end='')
        stars -= 1
    print()
    currentRow += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, after your while loop, the `stars` variable becomes `0` so you'll always print 4 astrix symbols. You can achieve this way easily, like the following:-

```py
maxRows = int(input("Enter the maximum number of rows: "))

currentRow = 0
while currentRow <= maxRows - 1:
    spaces = " " * (maxRows - currentRow)
    print(spaces, end="")
    stars = "*" * (2 *(maxRows - len(spaces)) + 1)
    print(stars)
    currentRow += 1
```

Comment: Thanks but I got a better solution